# Are there video players that display milliseconds on Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, video, mediaplayer

I need to view a video in "mp4" format with an accuracy of minutes, seconds and milliseconds for a specific task - analysis.

Operating system: macOS Catalina, version: 10.15.7

As I understand there are video players with milliseconds display only on windows, on Mac, alternatives and solutions could not be found. Maybe someone came across a similar question and was able to solve it. I have already tried to install the VLC player, but a certain plug-in is needed to open the ability to view in milliseconds, unfortunately I could not install such a plug-in on a Mac.macos
video

This error occurs when trying to open the file:

[image]

> The document "2020-12-24T09_20_45.375Z_LR_crf_26_deidentified.h.265.mp4" could not be opened.
>
> The file isn't compatible with QuickTime Player.

Comment: Which ones have you checked? Saves us having to duplicate...

Answer (score 11):

If you have `homebrew` installed, you can install `mpv` (recommended) or `IINA` (based on `mpv`) which displays milliseconds.

If you do not have homebrew then you can install it by copying pasting the following in your terminal:

```bsh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

**Solution 1:**
Install `mpv` with the following command:

```bsh
brew install mpv
```

`mpv` player supports url and a wide variety of video formats. That means you can play files locally as well as youtube or any other online video links straight from your terminal.

After installing `mpv` you can play your video file by going to the terminal and type:

```bsh
mpv <Drag the file you want to play from finder and hit enter>
```

At the beginning when `mpv` will open, it will not show you milliseconds. You would have to click on top of the time for it to display milliseconds.

For details see: https://mpv.io/ and their git repo: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv

Here is a screenshot of a non-copyright video playing from youtube with milliseconds displaying at the bottom:

[image]

**Solution 2:** Install `iina` with the following command:

```bsh
brew install --cask iina
```

It should let you install version `1.1.2` which supports this feature.

You can choose the timestamp in miliseconds as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why was it just downvoted, can someone explain ? It is perhaps better and indeed advisable to provide some explanation for improvements or submit an edit instead of unnecessarily downvoting, I reckon.

Answer (score 10):

You could open your video in QuickTime and use the trim view (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to see the milliseconds.

Comment: The fact is that QuickTime is not compatible with mp4 :((

Comment: @EkaterinaAndreeva mp4 is one of the few formats that quicktime is compatible with

Comment: @theonlygusti When I try to run file 4, the player shows an error that the file is incompatible and cannot be run.

Comment: @EkaterinaAndreeva then the video is in an incompatible codec. You should install [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (`brew install ffmpeg` if you have Homebrew) and then `ffmpeg -i your_video.mp4 output.mp4`, then you can open `output.mp4` in Quicktime and use TwlvSeconds' answer.

Comment: It looks like this rounds to centiseconds.

Comment: The best answer. No need to install anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The open source app [IINA](https://iina.io/) ([on GitHub](https://github.com/iina/iina)) can show the time in milliseconds.

You can install it [from its website](https://iina.io/) or with Homebrew: `brew install --cask iina`.

To make it show milliseconds, right-click the current time at the side of the video's scrubbing bar. It will show a "Precision" drop down. Select milliseconds to see the timestamp with milliseconds.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried IINA 1.2 and It seems that this feature either isn't working or has been removed. There is a request for it going back to 2017: https://github.com/iina/iina/issues/1003

Comment: @ThomasW I have 1.2.0 Build 129 mpv 0.32.0 and it still works for me

Answer (score -1):

You don’t strictly need milliseconds displayed. Your video has a video frame rate: 24, 30, 60, are standards. The standard SMPTE time code gives hour, min, sec, and frames. Divide the frame by the frame rate and that gives you the decimal seconds.

Unless the video was shot at a high frame rate — which even phones can do nowadays — you won’t actually have millisecond precision. So be careful to not misrepresent the actual precision — make the uncertainty clear.